# Misaligned Vertical pager in div in IE

Tags: html, css

i tried lots of things to solve but can't,

link : ediversified in home html

please use dot in first and third space in link and slash in second space, it was not allowing to post entrire link in question....sorry for this heck...

in above link there is a pager in main slideshow, please browse link in ie and firefox, pager is working good in firefox, but not in ie (mis aligned)...

wt can i do to solve it, please give suggestion.....

Comment: You have not provided a link. Please, post the relevant code.

Comment: There is no link in your question

Comment: Please provide the link.

Comment: @Ran i edited question.... second line is link....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got some whitespace in the `index-slideshow-pager` div. (Line 118 in the source). Try editing it so that it has nothing in it, aka:

```
<div id="index-slideshow-pager"></div>
```

And hopefully that should work. The problem is that IE pays attention to the spaces, even though the other browsers ignore the space.